# How do we use fonts stored in a folder in java

Tags: java, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make arbitrary font files available to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374964/how-can-i-make-arbitrary-font-files-available-to-java)

I am developing a GUI in java. I want to use some specific fonts like digital ones and all. Is there some way to use font from a folder in my workspace so that where ever I shift the workspace to some other computer, I donot need to reinstall the fonts again on that system, as the fonts are being taken from a folder which has been shifted along with my workspace.. This thing is possible in HTML using atfontface method.. Pls gimme some suggestions

Comment: [API reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.File))